# Reformatted for assistance within Python. Error is within the body

Tags: python-3.x

I have attached an image of what my code is. 
So far, I have spent many hours only attempting to upload this information into stackoverflow and to no avail, the site is still asking for further insight. I totally get it, however, it seems to be extremely restrictive.
I have taken the advice of many users and the site itself.`enter code here`

```
def main():
    corr_ans_list = ["A", "C", "A", "A", "D", "B",
                     "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "D",
                     "C", "A", "D", "C", "B", "B",
                     "D", "A"]
    user_ans_list = []
    corr_count = 0
    incorr_count = 0
    num_questions = 20
    infile = open('user_answers.txt', 'r')

    if user_ans_list[index].strip() == corr_ans_list[index]:

        infile.close()
        index = 0

print("Q\tocrr\tYour\tStatus")
print("#\tAnswer\tAnswer\n--------------------------")

while index < 20:                 
    print(str(index+1) + "\t" + correct_ans_list[index]+ "\t" + user_ans_list[index],end="\t" )
    if user_ans_list[index] == corr_ans_list[index]:
        corr_count += 1
        index += 1
        print("Correct")
    else:
        incorr_count += 1
        index += 1
        print("Wrong")

        percent_corr = (corr_count/num_questions) * 100
        percent_corr_fmt = format(percent_corr, ".1f")
        print("Grade : ", corr_count , "/", num_questions, " = ", percent_corr_fmt, sep="")

    if percent_corr >= 75:
        print("Congratulations!! You passed the exam")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you did not pass the exam")

main()
```

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not image. Also consider undeleting [the question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584920/here-is-the-updated-code-new-error-is-nameerror-name-index-is-not-defined) instead of posting it multiple times. You are simply wasting the times of the people who tried to help you on that one.

Comment: Any insight you have regarding how to do so is welcomed because I spent over an hour attempting to format the question into text and I was unable to post. So, I took the suggestion of stack overflow to create an image.

Comment: Simply edit your question, paste your code, then select all of it and click the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: I think the stack overflow tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a good place to learn how to format questions. The way the question stands, it's very hard to answer it - how would I know where's line 20? How can I paste the code to my notebook and try to debug it? Please, help us help you.